# How to get the Browser info in C# WebDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I see a ICapabilities interface to get the Browser info;Did couple of googling with no luck for any code example; Can anybody please share anything how I can get the browser info for a particular IWebDriver instance ? I am using C# webdriver.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to get info defined in ICapabilities interface, you need to cast IWebDriver instance to `RemoteWebDriver`. Then you can get the info about `BrowserName`, `IsJavaScriptEnabled`, `Platform` and `Version`.

```c#
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
ICapabilities capabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities;

// then you have
// capabilities.BrowserName;
// capabilities.IsJavaScriptEnabled;
// capabilities.Platform;
// capabilities.Version;
```

Comment: For Internet Explorer, capabilities.Version only returns the major version (11). Do you know how to get the minor version of IE as well?

Answer (score 1):

I use below code to get Chrome driver version

```
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    ICapabilities capabilities = ((OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver)driver).Capabilities;

    var SeleniumWebDriverName = driver.GetType().ToString();
    var SeleniumWebDriverVersion = (capabilities.GetCapability("chrome") as Dictionary<string, object>)["chromedriverVersion"];
    Console.WriteLine( "DRIVER NAME ====" + SeleniumWebDriverName );
    Console.WriteLine( "VERSION ====" + SeleniumWebDriverVersion + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the old Yi Zeng answer, I was able to acces with the next code:

```cs
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
ICapabilities capabilities = ((WebDriver)driver).Capabilities;
    
// then you have
// capabilities.GetCapability("browserName");
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I've stumbled across an easier way if you just need to know which driver is running to get around a hack:

Driver.GetType().ToString();